# Docker Nginx localhost in Windows 10 host file

Tags: windows, nginx, localhost, docker-compose

I'd like to try a Nginx Docker container but I don't know how I set the host file on a Windows 10 based on

> http://geekyplatypus.com/dockerise-your-php-application-with-nginx-and-php7-fpm/comment-page-3/#comment-2935

. Can somebody help me, please?

```
web:
image: nginx:latest
ports:
  - 8890:80
volumes:
  - ./code:/code
  - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
```

and

```
server {
  index index.php index.html;
  server_name php-docker.local;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  root /code;
}
```

It should work on php-docker.local:8890 address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a `docker ps` then `docker inspect <containerid> | grep IPA` and get the IP address. Put that in the host file

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working?